# Powershell in NonInteractive mode

Tags: powershell, deployment, octopus-deploy

I use Octopus for our deployments. I have a problem with one of the Powershell scripts to control the deployment:

```
# stops running processes
$processes = @("Notepad",
               "Firefox")
foreach ($process in $processes)
{
    $prc = Get-Process -Name $process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (-not($prc -eq $null))
    {
        Write-Host "Stopping " $prc.ProcessName
        Stop-Process -InputObject $prc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

The programs I try to stop are not the ones you see in the script above, but they represent what I am trying to do. Now the problem I have with it, is that it works well on one server, but not on another. Where it does not work, I get the error message:

**Stop-Process : Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.**

The script that works runs on Powershell 3.0, the one that does not work on Powershell 2.0. I cannot upgrade to Powershell 3.0 everywhere yet because the old servers run with Windows Server 2003. How can I make it work on PS 2.0?

Comment: Can you post the value of `get-executionpolicy` and `$confirpreference` from the server with version 2.0?

Comment: get-executionpolicy
RemoteSigned
$confirpreference

There was not output for $confirpreference.

Comment: Ops, my typo: $confirmpreference ...

Comment: $confirmpreference
High

Comment: try to add `-confirm:$false` to the stop-process cmdlet..

Comment: OK. I will try that on the next deployment. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to try it today. The Stop-Process worked without a problem. It works with -Force, it works with -confirm:$false and with both together. Thank you!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Run with `-Force`:

`Stop-Process -InputObject $prc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force`

As C.B. suggested in the comment: `-confirm:$false` should also work. Rationale for this is as follows: `-Confirm` is a switch parameter. Switch parameters can only take arguments if you specify the parameter with a trailing colon and a value.

Comment: I will give this a try as soon as I can. Our users are using the system frequently for testing and I cannot do deployments often. I ran the script this morning from Powershell ISE stopping Notepad and it worked well. Therefore the only way to check if the problem is resolved is to do an actual deployment.

Comment: Correction. Run with the `-Force`

Comment: I had Remove-Item with -Force in a DevOps deployment powershell script but was still getting this message.  So I'm going to try the -confirm:$false switch too.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried to use Remove-Item on the directory with children and got same message:
`Remove-Item : PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.`
In my case `-Recurse` key has helped.